# copy the entire block under another node - xslt transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am new to XSL coding, here i am trying to take entire block of **(result)** nodes and placing inside another node called  **RESULTS**... below is my xml and the xsl  used.

But its not transforming the xml as expected...

Could anyone help me where am i doing it wrongly?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="samplexslt.xsl"?> 
<report>
<Header>
 <RegNo>123</RegNo>
 <EmrNo>op2145</EmrNo>
 <BillNo>opcb1234-12</BillNo>
 <Uhid>1209</Uhid>
 <AdmissionDate>13-Jan-2014</AdmissionDate>
</Header>

<result>
 <name>test1</name>
 <desc1>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</desc1>
 <desc2>description</desc2>
</result>
<result>
 <name>test2</name>
 <desc1>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</desc1>
</result>

<Footer>
<DoctorSign>Anand</DoctorSign>
</Footer>
</report>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/report">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[local-name() != 'result']"/>
</xsl:copy>
<notes>
<xsl:apply-templates select="result" />
</notes>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="samplexslt.xsl"?> 
<report>
<Header>
 <RegNo>123</RegNo>
 <EmrNo>op2145</EmrNo>
 <BillNo>opcb1234-12</BillNo>
 <Uhid>1209</Uhid>
 <AdmissionDate>13-Jan-2014</AdmissionDate>
</Header>

<results>    
 <result>
  <name>test1</name>
  <desc1>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</desc1>
  <desc2>description</desc2>
 </result>
 <result>
  <name>test2</name>
  <desc1>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</desc1>
 </result>
</results>

<Footer>
<DoctorSign>Anand</DoctorSign>
</Footer>
</report>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `XSLT 2.0`? Your stylesheet declares `version="1.0"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move all `result` blocks in an added `results` block like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="result">
    <results>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following::result" mode="copy"/>
    </results>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="result[preceding-sibling::result]"/>
  <xsl:template match="result" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output, when applied to your input XML:

```
<report>
 <Header>
    <RegNo>123</RegNo>
    <EmrNo>op2145</EmrNo>
    <BillNo>opcb1234-12</BillNo>
    <Uhid>1209</Uhid>
    <AdmissionDate>13-Jan-2014</AdmissionDate>
  </Header>
  <results>
    <result>
     <name>test1</name>
     <desc1>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</desc1>
     <desc2>description</desc2>
    </result>
    <result>
     <name>test2</name>
     <desc1>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</desc1>
    </result>
  </results>
  <Footer>
    <DoctorSign>Anand</DoctorSign>
  </Footer>
</report>
```

The empty template `<xsl:template match="result[preceding-sibling::result]"/>` matches all result nodes that have preceding result nodes, so the `<xsl:template match="result">` matches only the first result.
In this template, using

```
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
```

copies the first result and then applies the template with `mode="copy"` for all following results:

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following::result" mode="copy"/>
```

This `<xsl:template match="result" mode="copy">` just copies all following `result` nodes inside the new `results` block.

Note that this approach, though working, can be kind of overcomplicating. In case your input XML only contains the known header, result and footer, I recommend just to use the XSLT provided in the detailed answer given by michael.hor257k.

Comment: if possible could you please give little explanation about the code you have provided?

Comment: @Thavudu Sure, but because I already explained all templates that I used (except the identity transform that you're already using in the code in your question) could you please give some details what I should explain further? This will also help me to improve answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Could anyone help me where am i doing it wrongly?

The main problem (there are several) with your approach is that you have placed the instruction:

```
<notes>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="result" />
</notes>
```

outside of the `<xsl:copy>` block - and therefore outside of the `report` element altogether. You should place it inside, and - if you want the results to come between the Header and the Footer - you must apply templates to them separately.

Other than that, if you want the results to be placed "*inside another node called **RESULTS***", then don't place them inside `notes`.

Note also that XML is case-sensitive: `RESULTS` is not the same thing as the `results` shown in your expected output.

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/report">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Header"/>
        <results>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="result" />
        </results>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Footer" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Of course, if that's *all* your stylesheet does, you could reduce it to:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/report">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Header"/>
        <results>
            <xsl:copy-of select="result" />
        </results>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Footer" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```